# (wx)Maxima: Assignments

Tags: arrays, variable-assignment, maxima, wxmaxima

I'm not certain of the language to use for describing the issue I've encountered, so I'll just illustrate it with an example.

Essentially, it seems that variable assignment with arrays works differently from variable assignment with non-arrays.

**Example 1:** numbers (behaviour = expected behaviour; description below):

```
(%i4)   foo1:0$
        bar1:foo1$
        bar1:1$
        foo1;

(%o4)   0
```

Here, I've assigned `bar1` to `foo1` and then reassigned `bar1` to `1` and then returned `foo1`. As expected, the value of `foo1` has not been changed.

**Example 2:** lists (behaviour = expected behaviour; description below):

```
(%i8)   foo2:[0,0]$
        bar2:foo2[1]$
        bar2:1$
        foo2;
(%o8)   [0,0]
```

Same idea as example 1, but with lists. N.B. the behaviour is the same if `bar2:foo2` and `bar2:[1,0]`, so I didn't include that case, here.

**Example 3:** array (behaviour != expected behaviour; description below)

```
(%i12)  foo3:[[0,0], [0,0]]$
        bar3:foo3[1]$
        bar3[1]:1$
        foo3;
(%o12)  [[1,0],[0,0]]
```

Here it seems that an assignment of an element of the list `bar3` also affects an the original array `foo3`.

I didn't think variable assignment worked like this -- it seems like an inconsistency to me; however, I have very little experience with programming.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The short answer that's the expected behavior, because `bar3:foo3[1]` is essentially telling you where is the list of items instead of just giving you the items. This "where is the stuff you want" is called a reference in computery terms.

Comment: Thanks Robert. What would be the "best" or "standard" practice for avoiding this issue, then? using `copy` all the time? I just had the same issue with `listA:listB`, `listB[1]:foo` resulting in `listA[1]` being assigned to `foo`, which I didn't expect (either).

Comment: Calling `copy` is a way to avoid changing the original list, as you know already. A more general approach, which I try to apply, is so-called functional programming, which just means programming without side effects. A side effect is something that happens aside from computing a function result. Assignment is a side effect, and so is printing output, so in a practical sense side effects can't be avoided entirely. However, to the extent that you can avoid side effects, it is easier to comprehend what is going on.

Comment: In the case of working with lists, for example, I try to think about transforming the whole list into another whole list, rather than walking down the list and modifying the elements one by one. E.g. `list2: map(lambda([x], if x > 0 then 2*x else x + 5), list1);` to create a new `list2` by modifying `list1`. A side-effect-ful approach would be something like `list2: copy(list1); for i thru length(list2) do if list2[i] > 0 then list2[i]: 2*list2[i] else list2[i]: list2[i] + 5;` That said, maybe `copy` makes the most sense for the problems you're working on; I wouldn't rule it out a priori.

Comment: Thanks for the clear guidance, Robert! Indeed, the stuff I'm working on is often lists of strings, where the value of one element requires the value of the previous / subsequent element to have been determined, already. Perhaps there is some way to achieve such transformations without side-effects but, if there are, they are beyond my level of insight, for now! Something for me to ponder, though. Cheers